# Powershell iterate through server list with credentials

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach, credentials

I've been lurking around grabbing code answers from this site for years, but this is my first time actually asking a question. I don't actually get paid to code, rather I use scripts to make routine tasks easier.

I've been using a powershell script with the following code (that I pretty much gleaned from this site) to gather disk usage on client servers:

```
$dataColl = @()#Makes an array, or a collection to hold all the object of the same fields

foreach ($serverName in (get-content c:\reporting\Disk_useage\My_servers.txt))

{

   $path = “\\$serverName\d$\folder1\TargetSubdir“

   $dirSize = Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -force | select Length  |Measure-Object -Sum length

   $dirSize.sum = $dirSize.sum/1MB

   $finalResult = “{0:N2} MB” -f $dirsize.sum

   $dataObject = New-Object PSObject

   Add-Member -inputObject $dataObject -memberType NoteProperty -name “ServerName” -value $serverName

   Add-Member -inputObject $dataObject -memberType NoteProperty -name “Dir_Size” -value $finalResult

   $dataColl += $dataObject  

   $dataObject

}

$dataColl | Export-Csv -noTypeInformation -path   c:\reporting\Disk_useage\Svr_disk.csv
```

This has been working fine, but we now have a 2nd domain with client servers, so I need to add credentials for servers in the 2nd domain. I've been researching ways to pass credentials along, and got this bit of code (PW has been stored already in the .TXT file):

```
$username = "MyDomain\MyAccount"
$password = cat C:\reporting\securestring.txt | convertto-securestring
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
     -argumentlist $username, $password
```

But I'm supposed to add these parameters somewhere to actually USE the credentials that have been set up:

```
-Authentication default -Credential $Cred
```

I've tried it in several different spots without success. FYI, the list in My_servers.txt has a bunch of servers I DON'T need credentials for (since they're on the current domain), and a bunch of servers where I DO need credentials (because they're on another domain). But the credentials I'm using for the script are for a service account that exists in both domains with the same ID/PW. Any help in sorting this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have WinRM configured, can you use invoke-command {d:\folder1\targetsubdir} -credential $yourcredentials etc to handle this differently? If not, coul you maybe try mapping the drives ?

Comment: I don't see how I would incorporate that. As I said, I'm not a coder by trade, so I'd need more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

Adil's suggestion in code would be:

```
$dataColl = @()#Makes an array, or a collection to hold all the object of the same fields
$username = "MyDomain\MyAccount"
$password = Get-Content C:\reporting\securestring.txt | convertto-securestring
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
     -argumentlist $username, $password
foreach ($serverName in (get-content c:\reporting\Disk_useage\My_servers.txt))

{
   $dirSize = Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ComputerName $serverName -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ChildItem “d:\folder1\TargetSubdir“ -recurse -force | select Length  | Measure-Object -Sum length
   }
   $dirSize.sum = $dirSize.sum/1MB

   $finalResult = “{0:N2} MB” -f $dirsize.sum

   $dataObject = New-Object PSObject

   Add-Member -inputObject $dataObject -memberType NoteProperty -name “ServerName” -value $serverName

   Add-Member -inputObject $dataObject -memberType NoteProperty -name “Dir_Size” -value $finalResult

   $dataColl += $dataObject  

   $dataObject

}

$dataColl | Export-Csv -noTypeInformation -path   c:\reporting\Disk_useage\Svr_disk.csv
```